# Problem returning viewmodel with Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to return a list of ProductDetailViewModel from the first select but nothing I do seems to work. What is the proper way to combine theese two selects?

```
            var test = (from pc in db.PartnerCoupons
                    from coup in db.Coupons
                    where pc.CouponID == coup.CouponID
                    && pc.PartnerCampaignID == partCamp.PartnerCampaignID
                          && coup.CategoryID == id
                    select pc).ToList();


        var partnerCoupons = from pc in test
                 .Select(s => new ProductDetailViewModel(s))
                 .ToList()
                    select pc;            


        return View("List", partnerCoupons);
```

Just to be clear, this works I just want to get rid of the "partnercoupons"-select.

/Mike

Comment: Just a note: there is no sense calling `ToList` if you use LINQ syntax because it would wrap it in another `Select`..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

return View("List", partnerCoupons.ToList());

Comment: Hi! Mayby I was unclear but this scenario works, I just want to get rid of "partnercoupons"-select.

Answer (score 0):

```
var coupons = from pc in db.PartnerCoupons
              from coupon in db.Coupons
              where pc.CouponID == coupon.CouponID
                  && pc.PartnerCampaignID == partCamp.PartnerCampaignID
                  && coupon.CategoryID == id
              select new ProductDetailViewModel (pc);

return View ("List", coupons.ToList ());
```

Comment: Hi! When I try that I get "Sequence contains no matching element" but if this is the proper way to do this it must be something else..

Comment: I don't think it is anyhow different from what you posted, except it's more compact. You would normally get such exception when calling `First` or `Single` when there are no such items..